# Question about derivative notation

Tags: derivatives

So i am studying for my calc test and i have a quick question
does $dy/dx$ means $y'(x)$?
and does $dy/dt$ means $y'(t)$?
Thanks

Comment: Is $y$ here a function of $x$, i.e., is $y=f(x)$?

Comment: The notation $\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}$ refers to the derivative of the function $y$ w.r.t $x$.

Comment: On a Calculus test, yes, the chances are that $dy/dx$ means $y'(x)$, and $dy/dt$ means $y'(t)$ --- but if you want to know for certain, you should be asking the person who is going to be marking the test, not random strangers on the internet.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: At least those *strangers* were not chosen *uniformly at random* ;)